# Logo particle animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

Im new to this area and hope some off you can help me.
I am super inspired be this site and the particle animation / function they have http://www.giantstepsmedias.com/

I found this one that are close to the inspiration. But i can't figure out how to change it to an images instead of the value in the input field.

```js
 var canvas = document.querySelector("#scene"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        particles = [],
        amount = 0,
        mouse = {x:0,y:0},
        radius = 1;

    var colors = ["rgba(255,255,255,1)","rgba(255,255,255,.5)", "rgba(255,255,255,.25)","rgba(255,255,255,.1)"];

    var copy = document.querySelector("#copy");

    var ww = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    var wh = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    function Particle(x,y){
        this.x =  Math.random()*ww;
        this.y =  Math.random()*wh;
        this.dest = {
            x : x,
            y: y
        };
        this.r =  Math.random()*5 + 2;
        this.vx = (Math.random()-0.5)*20;
        this.vy = (Math.random()-0.5)*20;
        this.accX = 0;
        this.accY = 0;
        this.friction = Math.random()*0.05 + 0.94;

        this.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*6)];
    }

    Particle.prototype.render = function() {


        this.accX = (this.dest.x - this.x)/1000;
        this.accY = (this.dest.y - this.y)/1000;
        this.vx += this.accX;
        this.vy += this.accY;
        this.vx *= this.friction;
        this.vy *= this.friction;

        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y +=  this.vy;

        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.fill();

        var a = this.x - mouse.x;
        var b = this.y - mouse.y;

        var distance = Math.sqrt( a*a + b*b );
        if(distance<(radius*70)){
            this.accX = (this.x - mouse.x)/100;
            this.accY = (this.y - mouse.y)/100;
            this.vx += this.accX;
            this.vy += this.accY;
        }

    }

    function onMouseMove(e){
        mouse.x = e.clientX;
        mouse.y = e.clientY;
    }

    function onTouchMove(e){
    if(e.touches.length > 0 ){
      mouse.x = e.touches[0].clientX;
      mouse.y = e.touches[0].clientY;
    }
    }

function onTouchEnd(e){
  mouse.x = -9999;
  mouse.y = -9999;
}

    function initScene(){
        ww = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        wh = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.font = "bold "+(ww/10)+"px sans-serif";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.fillText(copy.value, ww/2, wh/2);

        var data  = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ww, wh).data;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "screen";

        particles = [];
        for(var i=0;i<ww;i+=Math.round(ww/150)){
            for(var j=0;j<wh;j+=Math.round(ww/150)){
                if(data[ ((i + j*ww)*4) + 3] > 150){
                    particles.push(new Particle(i,j));
                }
            }
        }
        amount = particles.length;

    }

    function onMouseClick(){
        radius++;
        if(radius ===5){
            radius = 0;
        }
    }

    function render(a) {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            particles[i].render();
        }
    };

    copy.addEventListener("keyup", initScene);
    window.addEventListener("resize", initScene);
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    window.addEventListener("touchmove", onTouchMove);
    window.addEventListener("click", onMouseClick);
    window.addEventListener("touchend", onTouchEnd);
    initScene();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas{
    background: black;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="scene"></canvas>
<input id="copy" type="text" value="Hello Codepen ♥" />
```

Comment: It is very far from a trivial task to convert this from interpreting an ASCII value to reading the binary content of an image, interpreting what structure is being displayed within that image and organising the animation accordingly.

Comment: The relevant line of code is `ctx.fillText(copy.value, ww/2, wh/2);` - it *renders* the text onto the ctx then processes that rendering, *not* the text itself.   So it does seem trivial to instead render a simple image to the ctx rather than rendering text.  The rest of the process works on the rendered data.

Answer (score 1):

The animation is based on whatever has been rendered to the canvas.

In your code that is

```
    ctx.font = "bold "+(ww/10)+"px sans-serif";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText(copy.value, ww/2, wh/2);
```

instead, change this to render an image:

```
    const img = document.getElementById('img');
    ctx.drawImage(img, ww/2, wh/2);
```

you might like to adjust the positions for .drawImage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Using HTML:

```
<canvas id="scene"></canvas>
<div style="display:none;">
  <img id="img"
       src="http://www.giantstepsmedias.com/img/logos/giant_steps_small.png">
</div>
```

However, rendering an image from a different server to your ctx gives `The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data` so I can't give you a working snippet.

Use an image that is on the same server as the page or, as suggested, use a `data:` url:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("#scene"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  particles = [],
  amount = 0,
  mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  radius = 1;

var colors = ["rgba(255,255,255,1)", "rgba(255,255,255,.5)", "rgba(255,255,255,.25)", "rgba(255,255,255,.1)"];

var ww = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var wh = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function Particle(x, y) {
  this.x = Math.random() * ww;
  this.y = Math.random() * wh;
  this.dest = {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
  this.r = Math.random() * 5 + 2;
  this.vx = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 20;
  this.vy = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 20;
  this.accX = 0;
  this.accY = 0;
  this.friction = Math.random() * 0.05 + 0.94;

  this.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)];
}

Particle.prototype.render = function() {


  this.accX = (this.dest.x - this.x) / 1000;
  this.accY = (this.dest.y - this.y) / 1000;
  this.vx += this.accX;
  this.vy += this.accY;
  this.vx *= this.friction;
  this.vy *= this.friction;

  this.x += this.vx;
  this.y += this.vy;

  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fill();

  var a = this.x - mouse.x;
  var b = this.y - mouse.y;

  var distance = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
  if (distance < (radius * 70)) {
    this.accX = (this.x - mouse.x) / 100;
    this.accY = (this.y - mouse.y) / 100;
    this.vx += this.accX;
    this.vy += this.accY;
  }

}

function onMouseMove(e) {
  mouse.x = e.clientX;
  mouse.y = e.clientY;
}

function onTouchMove(e) {
  if (e.touches.length > 0) {
    mouse.x = e.touches[0].clientX;
    mouse.y = e.touches[0].clientY;
  }
}

function onTouchEnd(e) {
  mouse.x = -9999;
  mouse.y = -9999;
}

function initScene() {
  ww = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  wh = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  //ctx.font = "bold "+(ww/10)+"px sans-serif";
  //ctx.textAlign = "center";
  //ctx.fillText(copy.value, ww/2, wh/2);

  const img = document.getElementById('img');
  ctx.drawImage(img, ww / 2 - 75, (wh / 2) - 75, 150, 150);

  var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ww, wh).data;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "screen";

  particles = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < ww; i += Math.round(ww / 150)) {
    for (var j = 0; j < wh; j += Math.round(ww / 150)) {
      if (data[((i + j * ww) * 4) + 3] > 150) {
        particles.push(new Particle(i, j));
      }
    }
  }
  amount = particles.length;

}

function onMouseClick() {
  radius++;
  if (radius === 5) {
    radius = 0;
  }
}

function render(a) {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    particles[i].render();
  }
};

window.addEventListener("resize", initScene);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
window.addEventListener("touchmove", onTouchMove);
window.addEventListener("click", onMouseClick);
window.addEventListener("touchend", onTouchEnd);

initScene();
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas {
  background: black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="scene"></canvas>
<div style="display:none;">
  <img id="img" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: I believe you could use a base64 image to avoid the canvas origin issue, if you wanted to show a working example.

Comment: Please, **wait for the image has loaded in your code**.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the suggestion, but it still gives the tainted error after the image has loaded.

Comment: It wasn't about the CORS issue, just that you need to wait for the image has loaded before doing anything with it. We get too many questions about this, that I do fight against it in answers. If you wish to use a demo image, https://upload.wikimedia do serve all their images with the proper headers, so you'd just have to set the `crossOrigin` attribute of the <img>.

Comment: @Kalido do you honestly think I didn't try that?  I added a button and moved `initScene()/requestAnimationFrame` into the button click.  The image loaded, clicked the button - same error.  The canvas being `tainted` is caused **because the image *has* loaded** - if it hadn't loaded then it **wouldn't be tainted**.  If you have so many questions about this, perhaps you could provide an example question and *working* answer that calls `.getImageData()` after calling `.drawImage` with an image on an external server?  Also, if it's *not* a CORS issue then I wouldn't need to set `crossOrgin`.

Comment: TBH, the question was about changing from drawing text to drawing an image, which I hope this answers.  How/Why that image doesn't work on a canvas is for a different question (which will likely be a duplicate).